# Upload specific file types to another server (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

Imagine there are 2 servers:
**Server1** is the server that my WordPress website is currently hosted.
**Server2** is my download server where I upload big files in it for my users to download.

Now I want when I am uploading files with the format "mp4" in WordPress media, it uploads my file to server2. Otherwise, every file format except mp4 to be uploaded on server1 (main WordPress upload directory).

Is there any way to do this? Thank is advance!

Comment: There definitely is a way to do this. Does server1 have enough space for the file prior to transfer to server2? Are you using native wordpress uploader or a custom uploader?

Comment: It won't be simple. Use a CDN it should be possible using a plugin

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, server 1 has the space and I use native WP uploader.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126418/remote-upload-file-to-server-b seems similiar. IMO it would be easiest to handle the transfer with a CRON after the upload, you'd have to reserialize the data in DB though so it has the correct host.